# php `exec` calls python script. how return strings from python?

Tags: php, python

I use `exec` function calling python script from PHP script. Python writes to standard output two strings which I need in PHP script. The problem is that in these strings could be end of line characters `\n` ( so formally there are many lines in output), and according to [`exec` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) array `$output` will contain
each line in it. What is elegant way to escape `\n` characters so  that `$output` will contain only two string I want and no post processing of these two string needed?

EDIT: I can change python script.

Comment: Are you saying that your Python script can output new lines and you don't want the output to be interpreted as a new line? I am slightly confused by your question.

Comment: change the output of the .py file?...its not at all clear what you are trying to do ... what two lines?  just make the py file so it checks to make sure its not empty string before printing?... the other option is to post process it in php...

Comment: If the script is writing more than 2 newlines to the output, it's not writing "two lines" in any sense whatsoever.

Comment: yes sorry, I ment two strings. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the output in an easily parsable format, such as JSON, and parse it from PHP. For example, instead of:

```
print foo
print bar
```

Use something like:

```
import json
print json.dumps([foo, bar])
```

You read the JSON output form PHP and decode it using `json_decode($output)` into the desired array.

Comment: but how json escapes new line character?

Comment: @capoluca In this case, there would only be one line of output containing the JSON string.

Comment: JSON escapes newline as \n. If one of your strings contains a newline, it will appear as `"foo\nbar"` in the output, which `json_decode` will turn back into a newline on the PHP side.

Answer (score 2):

There really is nothing you can do about this outside of changing the way the python script outputs.

It is really easy to clean the returned data though.

```
exec('yourcommand', $array);
array_walk($array, function($value, $key) {
    return trim($value);
});
```

Comment: Or even `array_map("trim", $array)` :-P